# Definitions of boundary of a set in a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I think I'm just being finicky, but I'm having a hard time passing between two definitions. Specifically showing that in a metric space $(X,d)$
$$
  \partial S :=\{p \in X \; | \; \text{for every neighbourhood $O$ of $p$, } O \cap S \neq \varnothing \text{ and } O \cap S^c \neq \varnothing \}
 $$
is equivalent to
$$
 \partial S :=\{p \in X \; | \; \forall \varepsilon > 0, \; B(p,\varepsilon)\cap S \neq \varnothing \text{ and } B(p,\varepsilon) \cap S^c \neq \varnothing \}
$$
For reference a set $V$ is a neighbourhood of a point $p \in X$ if there exists some $r>0$ for which $B(p,r) \subseteq V$ is the definition of nbhd I'm using. Although I've also seen that a nbhd is any open set containing $p$.

I can see morally why this is right, and maybe that's enough, but is there anyway to show with maybe slight rigour that these are the same? I get that if any epsilon ball about $p$ contains points in $S$ and $S^c$ then any neighbourhood must as well because you get $B(p,\varepsilon) \subseteq B(p,r)$, but how can I convince myself in the opposite direction? Thanks in advance for the clarifications, and just lmk if this is just being needlessly pedantic.

Comment: Have you learnt about "basis for topology". You can prove that the open balls form a basis for the metric topology.

Comment: In the other direction, every ball $B(p, \varepsilon)$ is a neighborhood, since every point $x$ inside the ball is contained in some ball $B(x, \varepsilon - d(x, p)) \subseteq B(p, \varepsilon)$ by the triangle inequality.

Comment: I haven't @Mr.GandalfSauron, I'm unfortunately not taking a dedicated topology course, and we're just seeing these things in the context of real analysis.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow @TobErnack, because every epsilon ball is a nbhd, how do we conclude every nbhd has points in $S$ and $S^c$? It can't be that every nbhd is an epsilon ball right?

Comment: I think you already proved that direction in your last paragraph of the question. My comment was addressing the opposite direction: if every neighborhood contains points in $S$ and $S^c$, then so does every $\varepsilon$ ball, since they are also neighborhoods.

Comment: Oh thank you! I hadn't put together that the epsilon balls are themselves neighbourhoods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the set of nbhds of $x$ and let $B$ be the set of open balls that contain $x.$

(1). If every $\eta\in N$ intersects $S$ and $S^c$: Then every $\beta\in B$ intersects $S$ and $S^c$ because $B\subseteq N.$

(2). If every $\beta\in B$ intersects $S$ and $S^c$: Consider  any $\eta\in N.$ There exists an open $\eta'$ with $x\in\eta'\subseteq \eta$ and there exists an open ball $\beta$ with $x\in\beta\subseteq \eta'.$ So $\beta\in B.$ Therefore $$\eta\cap S\supseteq \eta'\cap S\supseteq \beta\cap S\ne \emptyset.$$ And replacing $S$ with $S^c$ in the previous sentence, we also have $\eta\cap S^c\ne \emptyset.$

Answer (score 1):

Every open ball is a neighborhood. Conversely, every open set contains an open ball.